# Terraform keeps updating aws_iam_policy_attachment

Tags: terraform

I am creating trying to use aws_iam_policy_attachment to attach two AWS managed policies and one custom policy. However, Terraform keep insisting to update to each plan even though apply has completed.

I'm stumped and help would be appreciated.

See below for my Terraform being applied.

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "test_amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "test_amazon_elastic_map_reduce_full_access" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess"
}

data "template_file" "test_assume_role_policy" {
 template = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
 name               = "${var.env}-test-role"
 assume_role_policy = "${data.template_file.test_assume_role_policy.rendered}"
 description        = "IAM role for granting test policies"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy" {
 name        = "${var.env}-test-policy"
 path        = "/"
 description = "IAM Policy for granting test permissions"
 policy = <<EOF
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
   ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy_attachment" {
 name       = "${var.env}-test-amazon-ecs-task-execution-role-policy-attachment"
 roles      = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
 policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.test_amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_amazon_elastic_map_reduce_full_access_attachment" {
 name       = "${var.env}-test-amazon-elastic-map-reduce-full-access-attachment"
 roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"]
 policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.test_amazon_elastic_map_reduce_full_access.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_policy_attachment" {
 name       = "${var.env}-test-policy-attachment"
 roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"]
 policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.test_policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the plan output?

Comment: i was able to resolve my issue using aws_role_iam_policy_attachment over aws_iam_policy_attachment. I found that aws_iam_policy_attachment is exclusive as defined here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html

Answer (score 0):

If we omit the typo in `roles      = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"` where you should use `[]` around the value, this code should work without any issues and should not ask to recreate resources unless you are providing different values for `var.env` on each run.

Meanwhile, you can leverage `aws_iam_policy_document` to make the code much more cleaner:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name               = "${var.env}-test-role"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_assume_role_policy.json}"
  description        = "IAM role for granting test policies"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_policy" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy" {
  name        = "${var.env}-test-policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM Policy for granting test permissions"
  policy      = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_amazon_ecs_task_execution_role_policy_attachment" {
  name       = "${var.env}-test-amazon-ecs-task-execution-role-policy-attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_amazon_elastic_map_reduce_full_access_attachment" {
  name       = "${var.env}-test-amazon-elastic-map-reduce-full-access-attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test_policy_attachment" {
  name       = "${var.env}-test-policy-attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.test_policy.arn}"
}
```